# Image has smaller height on initial load

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using React JS, though not so sure this is a problem specifically with React.

I have the following code that is supposed to set the maxHeight of an image to 60%. However, on first page load it show the image with a squished height. When I refresh the page, the image seems to have a height filling the entire div it is contained within.

If I open the page in a new browser tab, again I see the squished height until I refresh the page.

```
<div style={{display: "flex"}}>
   <div style={{flex: 1, border: "solid black 1px"}}>AAA</div>
   <div style={{flex: 2, textAlign: "center", margin: "20px"}}>
     <img style={{width: "100%", maxWidth: "100%",
              maxHeight: "60%", border: "solid black 3px"}} src="myimage.jpg" />
   </div>
   <div style={{flex: 1, border: "solid black 1px"}}>CCC</div>
</div>
```

What is wrong with my code here?

Comment: whats the actual image size (height and width)?

Comment: @Sagivb.g The actual image is 312px x 320px.

Comment: Have you tried setting `height` as well?

Comment: @Emily, I think for it not to be skewed I am not supposed to set the height. Also, the above is just a sample measurement of the image. In production, the images will be random sizes.